# Understanding c++ set

Tags: c++

I was reading c++ reference and found the following:

> Internally, the elements in a set are always sorted from lower to
>   higher following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on
>   container construction.

What does 'following a specific weak ordering criterion' mean? What does weak ordering mean?

Comment: Please don't tag this question `c`.

Comment: Dave Abrahams wrote an [article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/) on the classes of ordering, and exactly what `strict weak` ordering means.

Comment: -1: Googling for "strict weak ordering", the exact phrase the reference used, leads to the Wiki article that explains what it means. The same thing happens when Googling for "weak ordering".

Answer (score 1):

It essentially means a binary less-than comparison satisfying some criteria:

1. If A is less than B then B is not less than A
2. If A is not less than B and B is not less than A then A is equal to
   B
3. If A is less than B and B is less than C, then A is less than C

I guess one should add that a a value cannot be less than itself according to this ordering criterion.

An example of a comparison that satisfies these criteria for a primitive type is `operator<`.

Answer (score -1):

Well

In mathematics, especially order theory, a strict weak ordering is a binary relation < on a set S that is a strict partial order (a transitive relation that is irreflexive, or equivalently, that is asymmetric) in which the relation "neither a < b nor b < a" is transitive.

From Wiki! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering
Please use google first next time.